# Is there a Visual Studio keyboard shortcut that jumps to the end of a line and adds a semicolon?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I didn't see anything in [this list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx), but I may have missed it.

Comment: Yes. It's a two key combination. `End` followed by `;` works perfectly.

Comment: @KenWhite Fair enough. I didn't want to discuss the vagaries of my keyboard. The `End` key is poorly placed.

Comment: Since you tagged VB.NET, the good news is that you don't need semi colons there :)

Answer (score 3):

You can create the following C# command with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension and assign a shortcut to it:

```
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.LineEnd");
    (DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection).Text = ";";
```

Answer (score 2):

YES

If you are inside a string, you can press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to add a semi-colon to the end of the line and advance to the next line.

Tested in Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Commander, you can record a macro, customize it (if you want), and assign it a keyboard shortcut.

Open an arbitrary code file.

Record a macro by going to `Extensions` -> `VCmd` -> `Record a macro` (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+R</kbd>).

In the code file, press the <kbd>End</kbd> key, enter the semicolon character, and enter a new line by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Select `Extensions` -> `VCmd` -> `Save Macro as Command`.

Select `Extensions` -> `VCmd` -> `Commands`.

Select your new command. Select `Edit` to customize its name.

If you recorded the keystrokes well, the C# code of the command's Run() method should be the following:

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.LineEnd");
(DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection).Text = @";";
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.BreakLine");
```

Now you can assign a keyboard shortcut in an ordinary way. In `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Environment` -> `Keyboard`, search for "VCmd". You'll find commands named with numbers (i.e., not with your friendly name). Assign your desired shortcut.