# How to add semicolon faster?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm having trouble automatically adding semicolon at the end of the row (i'm using vs2019 newest version)
here is my illustration.

[image]

Can I type `;` and it manually added to the end of the line or how to switch to a new line combine add ; at the end of the row?

Currently I'm typing `);` and found it quite annoying. (`shift + enter -> edit.breakline` didn't work for me.)

If visual studio not supported, where can I find this add-on?

Comment: Seriously? You should really just learn to live with it. (maybe you could find some way to write a macro that replaces `;` with `);` every time you type, but that will surely backfire.)

Comment: Does the extension mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61445943/11613622) still works? On vscode, there are [many options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30118344/11613622) to do similar things but I'm not much sure if such extensions or keybindings are supported by visual studio also.

Comment: Hi @brc-dd, That's exactly what I need

Answer (score 2):

Instead of typing <kbd>)</kbd><kbd>;</kbd>, you *could* instead use <kbd>END</kbd><kbd>;</kbd>. That will at least save you reaching for the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key.

If, as you state in a comment, you cannot reach the <kbd>END</kbd> key for some reason, you could use [Macros for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MacrosforVisualStudio) or [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) (my preference, since I already use it for other things) to turn one of the (closer) function keys into that <kbd>END</kbd><kbd>;</kbd> sequence.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the suggestion! but my fingers are so short, I cannot reach the End key.

Comment: @Nguyen, I hesitate to suggest this in case you're physically less abled in some manner,  but have you tried using your elbow or shoulder? :-) Apologies if that seems flippant but the "finger too short" reason seems a little ... bizarre to me.

Comment: Yes it is, the backspace key is probably the limit for my hand to reach.

Comment: @Nguyen. is this because you're keeping in contact with the home keys (i.e., touch typing)? Given that the major component of coding is thinking rather than speed typing, that would be (in my opinion) a dubious reason. However, if you really cannot reach the end key, I'll add a macro solution.

Comment: Hi @paxdiablo, it makes me difficult to focus on coding. from brc-dd's suggestion, Productivity Tool is probably what I need. Thanks a lot for the help!